# access json data by creating dynamic key

Tags: javascript, json

json Data:

```
 var fruit = [{"apple":1000}, 
{"mango":100},{"orange":200}];

var user_input = "apple"; //this will change dynamically.

for(var key in fruit) {

 var val = fruit[key];
 console.log(val[user_input]);
}
output: undefined
```

i want to access the data using user input

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate through the `fruit` array to find the object that has the key.

```js
var fruit = [{"apple":1000},{"mango":100},{"orange":200}];
var user_input = "apple";

const obj = fruit.find((obj) => Object.keys(obj).includes(user_input));
if (obj) console.log(obj[user_input]);
```